# How to Transpose 2D Matrix Stored as C 1D Array

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

I have a 2D matrix

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

stored in C like this

```
int array[9] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

and I would like to get the transpose of that matrix like this

```
int array_t[9] = {1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6,9};
```

without converting the original array into a 2D one. How can this be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done by switching around the loops you would normally use to index it. If you wanted the original matrix you could loop through it with something like this

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    for (j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
        printf("%d ", array[j + i * 3]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

If we switch the `i` and `j` loops we can get the desired output as in the following sample program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int array[9] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    int i, j;

    for (j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
        for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            printf("%d ", array[j + i * 3]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

---

This is related to the mathematical definition of the transpose of a 2D matrix. The transpose operation on a 2D matrix swaps the rows with the columns, in the C program when we are indexing it we swap our row and column loops.

Comment: Very elegant solution that can be easily modified to become a general transposing function.