# How to transpose 2D square matrix stored as 1D array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

My question is closely related to this question but I'm looking for a solution in Javascript

[How to Transpose 2D Matrix Stored as C 1D Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404915/how-to-transpose-2d-matrix-stored-as-c-1d-array)

Basically I have a 2D square matrix

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Stored as follows

```
let anArray = [1 ,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

How can I transpose this matrix so that the elements of my source array are switched as follows?

```
let newArray = [1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6, 9]
```

Comment: does your matrix have a fixed number of lines and columns ?

Comment: The matrix I'm using is 3x3 in size but for the purposes of this question I would assume that I'm always to use a square matrix (could be 4x4, 5x5). I'll update the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take the length for the dimension of the array and map items on a specific index for a new array.

```js
var array = [1 ,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    n = Math.sqrt(array.length),
    transposed = array.map((_, i, a) => a[(i % n) * n + Math.floor(i / n)]);
    
console.log(transposed.join(' '));
```

Answer (score 2):

The approach in the answer you linked to works well in JavaScript too.

For a 3 x 3:

```js
const anArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

let newArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    newArray[3 * i + j] = anArray[3 * j + i];
  }
}

console.log(newArray);
```

For an N x N, just replace the 3's with N.

This answer avoids division and flooring (integer division) and a decent optimizer should make the code relatively fast. You might also consider initializing the new array with

```
let newArray = new Array(9);
```

or

```
let newArray = new Array(N * N);
```

but profile the code before attempting "optimizations" such as this.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr1 = [];
var arr2 = [];



for(int i=0; i<mat.length; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<mat[i].length; j++) {
        arr1.push(mat[i][j]);
    }
}

for(int j=0; j<mat[i].length; j++) {
    for(int i=0; i<mat.length; i++) {
        arr2.push(mat[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a max "width" for your matrix and insert into a new array in loops, offset by 1 for each run.

```js
function transpose(list, width) {
  if (width === void 0) {
    width = 1;
  }
  var t = 0;
  var transposed = [];
  while (t < width) {
    for (var index = t; index < list.length; index += width) {
      transposed.push(list[index]);
    }
    t++;
  }
  return transposed;
}
//TEST
var list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var transposed = transpose(list, 3);
console.log(list.join());
console.log(transposed.join());
```